# Exact Online - It is possible to match GeneralJournalEntry and BankEntry individual entry lines explicitly?

Tags: accounting, exact-online

### Bank Entry

First we created a **BankEntry** (a singular [BankEntries](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=FinancialTransactionBankEntries)) with entry line items as **BankEntryLine** (a singular [BankEntryLines](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=FinancialTransactionBankEntryLines)).

**BankEntry:**

```
| Entry Number |
| -------------|
|        10001 |
```

**BankEntryLines:**

```
| Amount      | Description         | Line Number      |
| ------------|---------------------|------------------|
|   -1,000.00 | bank:item:001       |                1 |
|   -1,000.00 | bank:item:002       |                2 |
|   -1,000.00 | bank:item:003       |                3 |
```

### General Journal Entry

Now we also created a **GeneralJournalEntry** (a singular [GeneralJournalEntries](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=GeneralJournalEntryGeneralJournalEntries)) with entry line items as **GeneralJournalEntryLine** (a singular [GeneralJournalEntryLines](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=GeneralJournalEntryGeneralJournalEntryLines)).

**GeneralJournalEntry:**

```
| Entry Number |
| -------------|
|        10002 |
```

**GeneralJournalEntryLines:**

```
| Amount      | Description         | Line Number      |
| ------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    1,000.00 | invoice:item:001    |                1 |
|    1,000.00 | invoice:item:002    |                2 |
|    1,000.00 | invoice:item:003    |                3 |
```

> Both entries are booked on G/L Account: **1600**

### Matching Process

Normally we match one of the two entries using xml matchsets structure.

e.g.

```
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">
  <MatchSets>
    <MatchSet>
      <GLAccount code="1600"/>
      <Account code="       0001"/>
      <MatchLines>
        <MatchLine finyear="2019" finperiod="8" journal="xx" entry="10001" amountdc="-1000.00"/>
        <MatchLine finyear="2019" finperiod="2" journal="xx" entry="10002" amountdc="1000.00"/>
      </MatchLines>
    </MatchSet>
  </MatchSets>
</eExact>
```

### Actual Result

This will make a successful matchset in exact online **however this matching process is not explicit and resulted in random matching**.

Current behaviour is something like this:

```
| Matched                                |
|----------------------------------------|
| bank:item:001  / invoice:item:003      |
| bank:item:002  / invoice:item:002      |
| bank:item:003  / invoice:item:001      |
```

### Expected Result

We would like to match the right item based on description (but the [xml documentation](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/XMLDocumentation.aspx?Action=1&_Division_=2396072#ELEMENT_MatchLine) doesn't provide a description attributes to be a criteria for matching entries).

We expect this kind of entry matching behaviour.

```
| Matched                                |
|----------------------------------------|
| bank:item:001  / invoice:item:001      |
| bank:item:002  / invoice:item:002      |
| bank:item:003  / invoice:item:003      |
```

Hopefully this is possible as we can't find the best solution how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple lines with the same amount for the same customer/supplier (Accounts in Exact Online) in 1 bank entry, it is not possible to choose what line you want to match.
In this scenario it is not possible.
To be complete : when the amounts differ, then these are unique enough for Exact Online to match.

Comment: thanks for answering and that is sad to know that apparently there is no way to explicitly match the entry line item. It would really be nice to have a feature that they can match line items based on description. With this there are also an underlying issue that 75% out of 100% are being matched (but randomly) and the rest of 25% are missing although we logged the process that it matched 100% of all the line items in the background tasks.